# How to format decimal in c# asp-format tag to 2 decimal points and without trailing zeros if it is an int?

Tags: c#, razor, format, asp.net-core-mvc, decimal

How to format decimal in c# asp-format tag to 2 decimal points and without trailing zeros if it is an int?

```
<input asp-for="X" asp-format="{0:0.00}" />
```

I need:

```
123.456 => 123.46
123.45  => 123.45
123.4   => 123.40
123     => 123
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

asp-format="{0:0.##}"

Comment: I don't think that will format 123.4 as 123.40. I suspect you'll need to do this by yourself. If the number is equal to the number converted to an integer, render it as an integer. If not, render it with two decimal points

Comment: @Flydog57, but this is not only output, it is in form input

Answer (score 0):

Your `asp-format` is correct. Change the format syntax:

```
asp-format="{0:n2}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).